# Number of independent equations in a set of nonlinear equations?

Tags: independence, nonlinear-system

For linear equations, we can use linear algebra to calculate the rank of the matrix to get the number of independent equations. When it comes to nonlinear equations, is there a similar theory to help us determine the number of independent equations?

Comment: In a sense, yes. Have a look at Groebner bases and systems of polynomial equations.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that!